# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

```
class Passport:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.age = age
        self.country = country
        self.duration = duration
        self.pstart_date = pstart_date
        self.pend_date = pend_date

    def show_passport_info(self):
        print("{} <-- ім'я за паспортом".format(self.name))
        print("{} <-- прізвище за паспортом".format(self.surname))
        print("{} <-- дата народження".format(self.birthday))
        print("{} <-- вік за паспортом".format(str(self.age)))
        print("{} <-- країна де видано паспорт".format(self.country))
        print("{} <-- строк на який видано паспорт (в роках)".format(self.duration))
        print("{} <-- дата видачі паспорту".format(self.pstart_date))
        print("{} <-- дата до якої діє паспорт".format(self.pend_date))

class Passport_international(Passport):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date, visa):
        Passport.__init__(name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date)
        self.visa = visa


pass_1 = Passport("Фи́лип", "Фрай", "1974-08-14", 37, "США", 10, "2015-01-01", "2025-01-01")
pass_1.show_passport_info()

pass_2 = Passport_international("Фи́липп", "Фрай", "1974-08-14", 37, "США", 10, "2015-01-01", "2025-01-01", "visa")
pass_2.show_passport_info()
```

ошибки при отработке pass_2:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\Yuliia\Python\itstep\Lab\03122020_s_lab\03122020_s_lab_2.py", line 31, in 
> pass_2 = Passport_international("Фи́липп", "Фрай", "1974-08-14", 37, "США", 10, "2015-01-01", "2025-01-01", "visa")
> File "E:\Yuliia\Python\itstep\Lab\03122020_s_lab\03122020_s_lab_2.py", line 24, in **init**
> Passport.**init**(name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date)
> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pend_date'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Почему ошибка не понимаю ( Помогите

Comment: Забыли self первым аргументом передать?

Comment: вместо `Passport.__init__` напишите `super().__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Passport_international(Passport):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date, visa):
        Passport.__init__(self, name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date)
        self.visa = visa
```

в строке

```
Passport.__init__(self, name, surname, birthday, age, country, duration, pstart_date, pend_date)
```

пропущен `self`